# "X questions with new activity" temporarily freezes the Chrome tab

Tags: bug, google-chrome, live-refresh

It seems that clicking on "X questions with new activity" results in a synchronous web request, or there is some other problem.

For example, I just clicked "18 questions with new activity" and there was a long period in which I couldn't use the tab. I don't know if this is a synchronous request to the server, or if it's the time taken to render the new display, but it's very annoying either way.

Can anyone at SE comment on this and ideally fix it?